# How to get the response after sending an email using amazon SES SMTP interface?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-mail, amazon-ses

The document says that after sending an email, no matter it was successful or not, SES will return a response to the sender, includeing message ID and an error if it wasn't sent successfully.
[image]
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-concepts-process.html

I am wondering how to get this response?

I am using SMTP and JavaMail to send emails, like:
`transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());`

The `sendMessage` method doesn't return anything. So how can I get the response?

Thanks in advance!

Update:

In https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=363239, it is said that

> SMTP returns the message ID appended to the OK response to the DATA command.
> For example: **250 Ok 0000aaaaccccaaaacccc-ccccaacc-aaaa-cccc-aaaa-acccccaaaaae-000000**

Could anyone teach me how to extract the message ID from the OK response?

Answer (score 1):

At best you can register a `TransportListener` with `Transport`, this listener will be called with `TransportEvent`. This TransportListener is called every time Transport object emits an events like `MESSAGE_DELIVERED`, `MESSAGE_NOT_DELIVERED`, `MESSAGE_PARTIALLY_DELIVERED`.

You can do something like this -

```
// Create a transport.
Transport transport = session.getTransport();

//Register your event listener
//This TransportListener is called every time Transport object emits an events like `MESSAGE_DELIVERED`, `MESSAGE_NOT_DELIVERED`, `MESSAGE_PARTIALLY_DELIVERED`.
transport.addTransportListener(new TransportListener() {
    @Override
    public void messageDelivered(TransportEvent transportEvent) {
        System.out.println("From Message Delivered");
        System.out.println(transportEvent.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void messageNotDelivered(TransportEvent transportEvent) {
        System.out.println("From Message Not Delivered");
        System.out.println(transportEvent.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void messagePartiallyDelivered(TransportEvent transportEvent) {
        System.out.println("From Message Partially Delivered");
        System.out.println(transportEvent.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it helps though hasn't solved my question. I found a thread, https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=363239, and it says `SMTP returns the message ID appended to the OK response to the DATA command.
For example: 250 Ok 0000aaaaccccaaaacccc-ccccaacc-aaaa-cccc-aaaa-acccccaaaaae-000000`. Could you teach me how to extract the message ID?

Answer (score 0):

I think that You can use configuration set for it. It only requires adding such header X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET with the value of the title of Your configuration set.

Here is full link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-java.html

Later, when You configure the configuration set, You can set it up to push the delivery, bounce, etc notifications on SNS. Which You can subscribe to in Your application.

Here is a link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-configuration-sets-in-email.html

And the link for the delivery object:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notification-contents.html#delivery-object

Answer (score 0):

I fugured it out.

I should used `getLastServerResponse()` method of `SMTPTransport` class, such as

```
        String response = transport.getLastServerResponse();
        System.out.println("response: " + response);
```

The output will be like
`response: 250 Ok 0100017352b73695-a103f18d-f0a3-4a48-9d86-db1df264a3fe-000000`